# Silhouette authorization using request data

Tags: scala, playframework, silhouette

I use **Silhouette** and **Play 2.4** and I'd like to restrict actions if a `SecuredRequest` body contains something wrong.

I know, I should use trait `Authorization` as described by [official docs](http://silhouette.mohiva.com/docs/authorization).

I'm trying to do the following:

```
case class WithCheck(checkCriteria: String) extends Authorization[User, CookieAuthenticator] {
  def isAuthorized[B](user: User, authenticator: CookieAuthenticator)(implicit request: Request[B], messages: Messages) = {

    Future.successful(user.criteria == checkCriteria)
  }
}
```

and than

```
def myAction = SecuredAction(WithCheck("bar")) { implicit request =>
  val foo = ...// deserialize object from request.body
  val checkCriteria = foo.criteria 
  // do something else here
}
```

How can I use the `checkCriteria` value in the class `WithCheck`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

Somehow, I was blind to see that `isAuthorized` has the same `request` as an implicit parameter. So, the check could be done entirely into the `isAuthorized`. For example,

```
case class WithCheck() extends Authorization[User, CookieAuthenticator] {
  def isAuthorized[B](user: User, authenticator: CookieAuthenticator)(implicit request: Request[B], messages: Messages) = {
    val foo = upickle.read[Foo](request.body.toString())
    Future.successful(user.criteria == foo.criteria)
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it means we have to parse the request twice. It seems like a bit of a design flaw in the `Authorization` trait since the type parameter `B` is useless.